# Compare builtin `setOf` with Android's `keySet`?

Tags: android, kotlin, keyset

Trying to ensure consistency concisely across my application. How do I check the bundle has the same keys as a set? - Or how do I construct a `keySet` succinctly for comparison?

```kotlin
import android.os.Bundle


fun main() {
    val expect = setOf("alpha", "beta")
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putCharSequence("alpha", "gamma")
    bundle.putCharSequence("beta", "zeta")
    assert(bundle.keySet() == expect)
    // Also tried `bundle.keySet().equals(expect)`
}
```

Output of `println("Expected $expect got $keys")`:

```
Expected [alpha, beta] got android.util.MapCollections$KeySet@48d26086
```

Comment: Are you doing this as a unit test?

Comment: No, just in my code. Haven't built tests yet. Yeah I know asserts need to be enabled with  flag

Comment: I tried your code by just sticking it in an Activity's `onCreate` and changing it to `require` and it passes fine, as expected. Haven't tried it with a unit test.